# Microsoft Bot Framework error - InternalServerError { "Message": "An error has occurred." }

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

When I pushed my bot code to azure it was successful. I tested it worked before pushing it to azure using node app.js

I updated my web.config file with the correct credentials

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');

var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Hi! What is your name?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send('Hello %s!', results.response);
    }
]);
```

When I look at the azure logs i get the following messages

```
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Executing: 'Functions.messages' - Reason: 'This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.'
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Function started (Id=22f4fffb-ad0d-4b54-b86f-dd895c098910)
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Function completed (Failure, Id=22f4fffb-ad0d-4b54-b86f-dd895c098910)
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 A ScriptHost error has occurred
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (internal/process/stdio.js:82:15)
    at ConsoleConnector.listen (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ConsoleConnector.js:11:60)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\index.js:3:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Function started (Id=22f4fffb-ad0d-4b54-b86f-dd895c098910)
2016-11-17T13:31:12.880 Function completed (Failure, Id=22f4fffb-ad0d-4b54-b86f-dd895c098910)
2016-11-17T13:31:12.895 Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: Error: Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (internal/process/stdio.js:82:15)
    at ConsoleConnector.listen (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ConsoleConnector.js:11:60)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\index.js:3:48)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19).
```

I do not know what this is or how this occurred.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully deploy Microsoft Bot Framework to Azure App Service with the following steps. Could you please have a try?

1.Once you’ve registered your bot, set the necessary environment variables in the Azure portal.

[image]

2.Get the `Bot Builder` and `Restify` modules using npm.

```
npm install --save botbuilder
npm install --save restify
```

3.Make a file named `app.js` and say hello in a few lines of code.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send("Hello World");
});
```

4.Go to the Microsoft Bot Framework portal and edit your bot details. Use the endpoint generated from your Azure deployment, and don't forget that when using the Bot Application template you'll need to extend the URL you pasted in with the path to the endpoint at `/api/messages`. You should also prefix your URL with HTTPS instead of HTTP.
[image]
5.Once you’ve gone through the steps here, you can test and verify that the Bot Framework can communicate with your Bot’s web service.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I will try this later on today and reply

Comment: I have followed your steps and I get Unauthorized.  I have check the application settings and generated the MICROSOFT_APP_ID and MICROSOFT_PASSWORD_ID. Still i get this message. any thoughts?

Comment: Have you removed the appid and password in the `web.config`?